# assembler phatom error, which i cant solve

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .data
buffer db 256 dup(0) ; буфер для ввода строки

section .text
global _start

_start:
; считываем строку с клавиатуры
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, buffer
mov edx, 256
int 0x80

; сохраняем длину строки
mov edi, eax

; переворачиваем строку
dec edi
mov esi, 0
.loop:
mov al, [buffer + esi]
mov bl, [buffer + edi]
mov [buffer + esi], bl
mov [buffer + edi], al
inc esi
dec edi
cmp esi, edi
jle .loop

; выводим перевернутую строку
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, buffer
int 0x80

; завершаем программу
mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
int 0x80`
```

when i want launch this program by "nasm -f elf64 -g -l lab05.lst lab05.asm" i get error: lab05.asm:2 error: comma expected after operand 1

i tried set comma after 256, after dup, but nothing happened

Comment: im sorry for the bad english and the poor formatting of the question, its my first time

Comment: Only recent versions of nasm support `dup` (version 2.15 and up). Instead try `buffer: times 256 db 0`. See also the [manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.5)

Comment: Its possible that a missing colon after buffer is the problem. Otherwise, try what Jester suggested.

Comment: @Plaisk: Colon after a label is optional in NASM syntax, as long as the label name isn't also an instruction mnemonic (e.g. `loop:` is allowed, `loop` on its own isn't.)  Most people consider it good practice to always use a colon, including in the data section where MASM syntax I think forbids it.